# Which Cocoa control to use to display drill-down table?

Tags: macos, cocoa

Any idea which Cocoa control to use to display the drill-down table as in attached screenshot?  On the left panel is a list of items. When an item is selected, the detail of the item is displayed on the right panel. Is it NSOutlineView or NSBrowser? Thanks!

[Screenshot http://s1.proxy03.twitpic.com/photos/large/409079140.png](http://s1.proxy03.twitpic.com/photos/large/409079140.png)

[Link to twitpic page](http://twitpic.com/6rjzhg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an [`NSTableView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on the left, and most likely an [`NSTextView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004140) on the right. The `NSTableView` on the left most likely has an `NSDateFormatter` set for the cell in the third column, which handles converting an `NSDate` object into the `NSString` value that's shown.

See [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000026i) for more general info on `NSTableView`s. There is also `NSOutlineView`, which is a subclass of `NSTableView`, for when you need to display a data tree. Implementing a table view is much easier than an outline view or `NSBrowser`, so only go with an outline view if you really need to.

Answer (score 2):

NSOutlineView will produce something like the left panel, but is probably overkill judging by your screenshot.

NSBrowser would give you a Finder-style drill down.

I would personally use two views - an NSTableView on the left and an NSTextView on the right.